# Union ALL fetches empty rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have two query joined with a `union All`.

```
SELECT  select 'Finished' AS Status,amount AS amount,units As Date
from table1 WHERE Pdate > cdate AND name =@name
UNION ALL
SELECT  select 'Live' AS Live,amount,units 
from table1  Where Pdate = cdate And name =@name
```

Result

```
Status     amount   units
Finished     100    20
Live         200    10
```

When either of the query fetches empty set I get only one row and, if both fetches empty set then I no rows

So how can I get result like this

```
Status     amount   Units
Finished     100    20
Live         0      0
```

OR

```
Status     amount   Units
Finished     0      0
Live         200    10
```

OR

```
Status     amount   Units
Finished      0          0
Live          0          0
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are selecting units as Date and 'Live' as Live. Shouldn't that be units As units and 'Live' as Status?

Answer (score 1):

I would think you can do it using sum? And if sum doesn't return 0 when there are no rows then replace with `Coalesce(sum(amount), 0) as amount`

```
SELECT  select 'Finished' AS Status,sum(amount) AS amount, sum(units) As Unit
from table1 WHERE Pdate > cdate AND name =@name
UNION ALL
SELECT  select 'Live' AS Status, sum(amount) as amount, sum(units) as Unit
from table1  Where Pdate = cdate And name =@name
```

And if you are not trying to sum the results then just coalesce should work? `coalesce(amount, 0) As amount` etc...

Comment: You probably need a `GROUP BY` in your `SELECT` statements.

Comment: I don't think so... I was assuming he wanted to sum all the records.

Comment: +1, OP wants to display both rows regardless of number of qualifying records (0..n) in each branch. But I think OP wants nulls displayed as zeros.

Comment: Ok, thats fine what if the column is not INT data type will coalesce work?

Comment: Yes, it takes any types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: But as per OP he gets the empty resultset that means he is not getting even a single row.In that case it wont work because it wont return any row null or not null.Also if query returns more than one row then he will get the sum instead of individual rows.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out that your query is needlessly complex, with nested selects and a union all.  A better way to write the query is:

```
select (case when pdate > cdate then 'Finished' else 'Live' end) AS Status,
        amount AS amount, units As Date
from table1
WHERE Pdate >= cdate AND name = @name
```

This query does not produce what you want, since it only produces rows where there is data.

One way to get the additional rows is to augment the original data and then check if it is needed.

```
select status, amount, units as Date
from (select Status, amount, units,
             row_number() over (partition by status order by amount desc, units desc) as seqnum
      from (select (case when pdate > cdate then 'Finished' else 'Live' end) AS Status,
                    amount, units, name
            from table1
            WHERE Pdate >= cdate AND name = @name
           ) union all
           (select 'Finished', 0, 0, @name
           ) union all
           (select 'Live', 0, 0, @name
           )
          ) t
where (amount > 0 or units > 0) or
      (seqnum = 1)
```

This adds in the extra rows that you want.  It then enumerates them, so they would go last in any sequence.  They are ignored, unless they are the first in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
with stscte as
(
select 'Finished' as status
union all 
select 'Live'
),
datacte
as(
select 'Finished' AS Status,amount AS amount,units As Date 
from table1 WHERE Pdate > cdate AND name =@name 
UNION ALL 
select 'Live' ,amount,units  
from table1  Where Pdate = cdate And name =@name 
)
select sc.status,isnull(dc.amount,0) as amount,isnull(dc.unit,0) as unit 
from stscte sc left join   datacte dc
on sc.status = dc.status
```